# Вопрос про преобразование типов

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица, в ней есть два поля размерностью tinyint (значения от 1 до 100)
Запрос `select sum (b*l) from stat` выдает arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type tinyint. Почему?

Comment: Потому что конечный результат не должен превышать *tinyint* вам нужно вначеле преобразовать `cast(b as int)` а потом умножать

Comment: Почему  'select sum (b*1000) from stat'  нормально отрабатывает?

Comment: Потому что 1000 не tinyint т.е. `tynyint*int` = int , а два tinyint*tinyint = tinyint.